# python sum all previous values in array at each index

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, sum

I have an array:

```
my_array = [1, 4, 1, 13, 9]
```

and would like to create a new array that for each index in my_array is the sum of all the previous index values

```
summed_array = [0, 1, 5, 6, 19]
```

I tried something like

```
for ind,i in enumerate(my_array):
    print i, my_array[ind-1]
```

but can't figure out how to get the summation over all previous values.

Comment: you can use `np.cumsum`

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> from numpy import cumsum, ones
>>> a = ones(10)
>>> print(cumsum(a))
array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.])
```

Comment: @IanAuld: It's in the tags, so they're probably already using it.

Answer (score 3):

Hereby another variant of the above using list comperhension:

```
[sum(my_array[0:i[0]]) for i in enumerate(my_array)]
```

enumerate is handy to use since it creates tuples containing the index and value at that index

Answer (score 2):

A pure Python implementation:

```
def cumilative_sum(lst):
    total, result = 0, []
    for ele in lst:
        result.append(total)
        total += ele
    return result
```

Comment: When the linear-time solution is so easy, please don't use quadratic-time solutions.

Comment: @user2357112, how is this solution quadratic-time?

Comment: @JohnK: See the edit history. It was quadratic time when I left that comment.

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.accumulate` would work  the same as `numpy.cumsum`:

```
from operator import add
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import add

def cum_sum(l):
   return accumulate(l, add)

In [22]: list(cum_sum(my_array))
Out[22]: [1, 5, 6, 19, 28]
```

which will match cumsum exactly.

If you want to ignore the last element:

```
from operator import add
from itertools import islice, accumulate


def cum_sum(l, take):
   return accumulate(islice(my_array, 0, len(l)-take), add)

In [16]: list(cum_sum(my_array, 1))
Out[16]: [1, 5, 6, 19]
```

To exactly match your output including the 0 and to work in python2 or 3 you can create a generator function:

```
my_array = [1, 4, 1, 13, 9]

def cum_sum(l):
    sm = 0
    for ele in l:
        yield sm
        sm += ele
```

Output:

```
In [5]: my_array = [1, 4, 1, 13, 9]

In [6]: list(cum_sum(my_array))
Out[6]: [0, 1, 5, 6, 19]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
np.cumsum(my_array) - my_array
```

`np.cumsum` returns an array of cumulative sums, with each sum going up to and including the corresponding element in the input array. You want to exclude the corresponding elements from the sum, so just subtract them out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concise and understandable implementation:

```
sum = 0

my_array = [1, 4, 1, 13, 9]
summed_array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for ind,i in enumerate(my_array):
    summed_array[ind] = sum
    sum += my_array[ind]
```

The code basically starts assigning sum with 0 and putting it into the first index of `summed_array`, and then it adds each respective index of `my_array` to sum. Then, it comes back to the `for` loop and assigns each index of `summed_array` with the previous `sum`.

The output would be:

```
>>> summed_array

[0, 1, 5, 6, 19]
```

...which is the final expected sums.

**EDIT:** Thanks @IanAuld, he suggested another method to do it without enumeration and initializing values to 0:

```
sum = 0

my_array = [1, 4, 1, 13, 9]
summed_array = []

for i in my_array:
    summed_array += [sum]
    sum += i
```

Comment: What's concise about creating a separate list of 0's and using enumerate and indexing instead of the values in the list directly?

Comment: @IanAuld Yeah, neat suggestion! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach could be:

```
def cumulative(lst):

    cumulative= []
    for x in range(0, len(cumulative)):
        if x == 0:
            cumulative.append(lst[x])  # Establish the first element
        else:
            cumulative.append(accumulated[x - 1] + lst[x]) # Makes the cumulative sum

return cumulative
```